# Binomial Probability Formula (inclusive?)

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Having some trouble with these two...

Suppose a health insurance company can resolve 60% of claims using a computerised system, the remaining needing work by humans. On a particular day, 10 claims arrived,
assuming claims are independent, what is the probability that:

Q2.1) Either 3 or 4 (inclusive) claims require work by a human?

Q2.2) No more than 9 claims require work by a human?

I have identified that:

$n=10,
p=0.6,
q=0.4$

How would I go about these questions? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2.1, we can separately compute $3$ or $4$ claims needing human intervention.

For $3$ claims, we have $\displaystyle \binom{10}{3}(0.6)^7(0.4)^3$, and for $4$ claims, we have $\displaystyle \binom{10}{4}(0.6)^6(0.4)^4$. We simply add these probabilities up.

For 2.2, rather than adding up everything from $0$ to $9$, we can just compute $10$, and do $1-$that probability. For $10$, we have $(0.4)^{10}$.

Comment: The general formula for $P(X=k)$ is $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}$.